# In SQL select statement, why use "1 order by " or "order by 1"?

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL select statement sometimes we need to use `order by 1` or `1 order by`. What is the main difference between them ?

Comment: `1 order by` just sounds wrong... Can you share the entire query please?

Comment: Nothing wrong is with `1 ORDER BY` - it will "work", but, however, it's pointless.

Comment: `select id,name,emp_id from user where is_active!=0 and 1 order by emp_id` - Here is my query and works. In this query, if I use **order by 1** then show error or if I use only **order by**  then also show error. Why?

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER BY 1` means that you want to order your results by the first field in the select. Instead of 1 you can write the first field name (or alias if there is one).

in the `1 ORDER BY` the 1 is part of the previous clause in your SQL. That's not linked to the order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by 1`.
`1` indicates the column in your `select` clause - the first column.

`select col1, col2 from t1 1 order by` throws a syntax error.

Comment: This is not so. `1 ORDER BY` is [completely valid](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51d875/1) - it's just need to be remembered about indexed columns - but, for example, even `SELECT 1 ORDER BY 1` will work (but not `SELECT 1 ORDER BY 2`, since there is only 1 column in result set)

Comment: `select col1, col2 from t1 1 order by` is not valid

Comment: It is not - because you're now referring to a very specific case with trying to set invalid alias name. While it can be "part of query" - either it should be mentioned specifically - or it is still not correct to say that `ORDER BY 1` throws syntax error in general. But that's my point only

Comment: @AlmaDo: `1 order by` **is** invalid. Unless the `1` actually belongs to a completely different part of the query - as in your example where the `1` it is part of the `SELECT` list. It's **not** part of the `order by` expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,name,emp_id
from user
where is_active!=0
and 1
order by emp_id
```

Here the line `and 1` can be completely ignored, because it is just a second condition, which is always true. The records will be ORDER BY the column `emp_id`

```
select id,name,emp_id
from user
where is_active!=0
and 1
order by 1
```

Here the records will be sorted by the first column in `SELECT`, i.e. `id`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `and 1` is invalid in standard SQL (and Oracle and Postgres **will** reject that) MySQL implicitly treats that as a boolean value - `and 'foo'`  would be valid as well